# How to convert this asp.net MVC code from c# to vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-to-vb.net

I need a quick hand figuring out what this code is doing, and how to make it work in vb.net

```
<%=Html.PageLinks((int(ViewData["CurrentPage"], (int)ViewData["Totalpages"], x=> Url.Action("List", new {page = x})) %>
```

i've figured out most of it.  but the  x=>Url.Action("List", new {page = x}) part is throwing me off.  I tried reading about lamdas and such but i'm not quite getting it.

the pagelinks is defined like this:

_

```
Public Function PageLinks(ByVal html As HtmlHelper, ByVal currentPage As Integer, ByVal totalPages As Integer, ByVal pageUrl As Func(Of Integer, String)) As String
            Dim result As New StringBuilder
            For i As Integer = 1 To totalPages
                Dim tag As New TagBuilder("a")
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i))
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString
                If i = currentPage Then
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected")

                End If
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString())
            Next
            Return result.ToString
        End Function
```

which i THINK is the correct conversion from c#.

Thanks in advance!

Patricia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct conversion of C#:

```
x=> Url.Action("List", new {page = x})
```

would be in VB.Net:

```
Function(x) Url.Action("List", New With {.page = x})
```